# What do time dummies look like in R?

Tags: r, plm

I have a question regarding pgmm function in plm package of R.

I saw an example code:

```
library(plm)
data("EmplUK", package = "plm")
emp.gmm <- pgmm(log(emp)~lag(log(emp), 1:2)+lag(log(wage), 0:1)+log(capital)+
                lag(log(output), 0:1)|lag(log(emp), 2:99),
                data = EmplUK, effect = "twoways", model = "twosteps")
summary(emp.gmm)
```

and as stated in the usage of pgmm function, I realised that summary part can be like this:

```
summary(emp.gmm, time.dummies = TRUE)
```

I tried both codes and got two different tables. The first result is without setting `time.dummies = TRUE`, the second one is with `time.dummies = TRUE`.

```
Unbalanced Panel: n = 140, T = 7-9, N = 1031

Number of Observations Used: 611

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.6190677 -0.0255683  0.0000000 -0.0001339  0.0332013  0.6410272 

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
lag(log(emp), 1:2)1     0.474151   0.185398  2.5575 0.0105437 *  
lag(log(emp), 1:2)2    -0.052967   0.051749 -1.0235 0.3060506    
lag(log(wage), 0:1)0   -0.513205   0.145565 -3.5256 0.0004225 ***
lag(log(wage), 0:1)1    0.224640   0.141950  1.5825 0.1135279    
log(capital)            0.292723   0.062627  4.6741 2.953e-06 ***
lag(log(output), 0:1)0  0.609775   0.156263  3.9022 9.530e-05 ***
lag(log(output), 0:1)1 -0.446373   0.217302 -2.0542 0.0399605 *
```

```
Unbalanced Panel: n = 140, T = 7-9, N = 1031

Number of Observations Used: 611

Residuals:
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.6190677 -0.0255683  0.0000000 -0.0001339  0.0332013  0.6410272 

Coefficients:
                         Estimate Std. Error z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
lag(log(emp), 1:2)1     0.4741506  0.1853985  2.5575 0.0105437 *  
lag(log(emp), 1:2)2    -0.0529675  0.0517491 -1.0235 0.3060506    
lag(log(wage), 0:1)0   -0.5132048  0.1455653 -3.5256 0.0004225 ***
lag(log(wage), 0:1)1    0.2246398  0.1419495  1.5825 0.1135279    
log(capital)            0.2927231  0.0626271  4.6741 2.953e-06 ***
lag(log(output), 0:1)0  0.6097748  0.1562625  3.9022 9.530e-05 ***
lag(log(output), 0:1)1 -0.4463726  0.2173020 -2.0542 0.0399605 *  
1979                    0.0105090  0.0099019  1.0613 0.2885484    
1980                    0.0246512  0.0157698  1.5632 0.1180087    
1981                   -0.0158019  0.0267313 -0.5911 0.5544275    
1982                   -0.0374420  0.0299934 -1.2483 0.2119056    
1983                   -0.0392888  0.0346649 -1.1334 0.2570509    
1984                   -0.0495094  0.0348578 -1.4203 0.1555141
```

Here I want to know what do time.dummies mean and what do time.dummies look like. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `effect = "twoways"` in the `pgmm()` call, you include two-way fixed effects, that is fixed effects on the panel group level, and the time level.

Fixed effects are basically dummy variables for all groups, and timesteps included in the model. (The actual implementation is a little more involved, but the result can be proven to be identical.) You would include these if you expect for example a shock that affects all panel groups at a certain timestep. To not bias your coefficient estimates, you must include a fixed effect, which captures the impact of the shock on the dependent variable at a given timestep (a year in your case).

The `time.dummies` option either includes, or excludes the coefficients of the time fixed effects in the output. Note that the model is estimated with the fixed effects (remember the `effect` option in the `pgmm()` call).

All coefficients of the time dummies are statistically insignificant, so interpreting is not informative. An estimate of `0.0105090` for the year `1979` means that on average across panel groups, in 1979 the logarithm of employment is larger by `0.0105090` compared to the average across all years. The coefficient estimate is not statistically significant though, so this interpretation should be handled with caution.

For more information, also on the theory, check chapter 1.1.1.3 in [Panel Data Econometrics with R](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781119504641), by Croissant and Millo (the developers of the `plm` package).